# Issue- Flutter plugin : google_maps_webservice^0.0.20-nullsafety.5" "fields" Attribute gives error

Tags: flutter

I am using this "google_maps_webservice^0.0.20-nullsafety.5" in flutter
Can some one please let me know, what I am  doing wrong here

Signature:
Future  getDetailsByPlaceId(
String placeId, {
String? sessionToken,
List  fields = const [],
String? language,
String? region, }
)

Here is how I am using it

```
  PlacesDetailsResponse detail =
      await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(
          p.placeId.toString(),
          fields: ['name'],     // Commenting out this line, would make it work, but i need this attribute/property to save cost
          language: 'fr',
          region:"fr",
      );
```

Issue:
fields: ['name'] => this "fields" attribute keeps failing,
I have seen so many tutorials , all are suggesting the same way,
but still it fails  with the below message

E/flutter ( 9854): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
E/flutter ( 9854): #0      _$PlaceDetailsFromJson (package:google_maps_webservice/src/places.g.dart:138:31)
E/flutter ( 9854): #1      new PlaceDetails.fromJson (package:google_maps_webservice/src/places.dart:710:7)
E/flutter ( 9854): #2      _$PlacesDetailsResponseFromJson (package:google_maps_webservice/src/places.g.dart:294:26)
E/flutter ( 9854): #3      new PlacesDetailsResponse.fromJson (package:google_maps_webservice/src/places.dart:838:7)
E/flutter ( 9854): #4      GoogleMapsPlaces._decodeDetailsResponse (package:google_maps_webservice/src/places.dart:528:29)
E/flutter ( 9854): #5      GoogleMapsPlaces.getDetailsByPlaceId (package:google_maps_webservice/src/places.dart:126:12)
E/flutter ( 9854): 
E/flutter ( 9854): #6      _LocationPickerInitialState.goToPlace (package:myproj/screens/maps/initialOwnerLocationpicker.dart:149:11)
E/flutter ( 9854):

Here is how I am using it

```
  PlacesDetailsResponse detail =
      await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(
          p.placeId.toString(),
          fields: ['name'],     // Commenting out this line, would make it work, but i need this attribute/property to save cost
          language: 'fr',
          region:"fr",
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the mapping class code for result (`PlaceDetails`) from google_maps_webservice, field placeId is not nullable but should be.

You have two option, use `fields: ['name', "place_id"]` or fork google_maps_webservice and make placeId nullable.